# Нужна помощь с js/ блок крутится эффект монетки

Tags: javascript

Сделал анимированный блок который крутиться(по принципу монетки), по нажатию на блок он становится лицом, по нажатию еще раз - задом, добавил инпут в блок, и теперь по нажатию на него блок тоже крутиться, как исправить?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.wrap').click(function() {
    //var wrap = $('.wrap');
    if ($(this).css('-webkit-transform') == 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)') {
      $(this).css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(180deg)'
      });
    } else {
      $(this).css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(0deg)'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="front">
    <h2>2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <div class="textbl1">
      <p>Если вы открыли билет, мы надеемся, что вы отгадали загадку </p>
      <form>
        <div class="group">
          <input type="text" required />
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <label>Password</label>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: стили добавьте в вопрос

Comment: а лучше рабочий пример

Comment: Это нормальное поведение... А что именно исправить и какой должен быть конечный результат не понятно

Answer (score 0):

не знаю как это в точности сделать на jquery (т.к. не знаю самого jquery и работаю с нативным js), но я думаю, вы сейчас поймете принцип и сможете быстренько нагуглить работу с событиями в jq.

```
var wrap = document.body.querySelector('.wrap');
var style = getComputedStyle(wrap);

wrap.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target === wrap) {

        if (style.webkitTransform === 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)') {
            wrap.style.webkitTransform = 'rotateY(180deg)'

        } else {
            wrap.style.webkitTransform = 'rotateY(0deg)'
        }
    }
});
```

В event.target будет содержать ссылку на самый глубоко вложенный элемент над которым находился в момент клика курсор (в данном случае на инпут), а не на контейнер wrap.

Comment: собственно https://api.jquery.com/event.target/